# string value validation in C#

Tags: c#, string, validation, c#-2.0

There is two variable was assigned the value of "003" and "00 3". And it was convert to byte[] as below.

Before:

```
myStr1 = "003"; // valid, there is no blank inserted.
myStr2 = "00 3"; // invalid, there is one blank character or multi blanks character inserted.
```

After converted by convert(), if there are blank characters found, the source string will be convert to byte array.

```
myVal1 = "3";  // valid after convert
myVal2[0] = 0; // invalid, since the source myStr2 is invalid.
myVal2[1] = 1; // same as above.
```

And now I need determine the source string is valid or invalid based on the converted result. I dont' know how to say the result is an byte array. Could you please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

input string type source value as SourVal

```
if (ResultVal is Byte Array) // how to translate the statement to C# code?
   SourVal is Invalid;
else if (ResultVal is still String type) // how to translate the statement to C# code?
   SourVal is valid;
```

ps: I failed to try the methods of typeof() and gettype() at my practice. I don't know how to use the methods. Or there is other better method for my validation.

Comment: Can you show more code and explain better what you are trying to accomplish?  Your convert function would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe use:

```
        if (ResultVal is byte[]) {
           // SourVal is Invalid;
        } else if ( ResultVal is String ) { 
            //SourVal is valid;
        }
```

Comment: `ResultVal is List<byte>`. Works on my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x308yk8.aspx#Y1000)

Comment: `IsWhiteSpace` is a good method I never used. But I maybe can't use it in my practice. I need to handle the `ResultVal` as the arguments. There is no White space any more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Check the String for Blank spaces if found then don't convert

if(!str.Contains(" "))

{

//use the convert method 

}
else

{

//Write Message for an Invalid String

}
```